# Use an interface from a different module as a top level interface

Tags: generics, typescript

The Node MongoDB driver has an option for the [`MongoClient.connect()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) method where you can pass an options hash containing a `promiseLibrary` value.  Currently I have [hacked a version of the mongodb.d.ts](https://github.com/AJamesPhillips/DefinitelyTyped/blob/692b8d40c35bf54e42c8a599e9bf19c009c2bd7e/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts#L24) to only use the [`q` async library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).  To avoid using return types of `q.Promise<T>` everywhere and instead use `Promise<T>`.  Is there a way to do declare the Promise interface, something like:

```
interface Promise<T> extends q.Promise;
```

Currently this produces the following error:

```
Generic type 'Promise<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst trying to refine and generalise the question I found the answer was:

```
interface Promise<T> extends q.Promise<T> {}
```

For example:

```
declare module FirstModule {
    interface SomeGeneric<T> {
        finally(): SomeGeneric<T>;
    }
    export function resolve<T>(object: T): SomeGeneric<T>;
}

declare module SecondModule {
    interface SameGeneric<V> extends FirstModule.SomeGeneric<V> {}

    interface Thing {
        Method<U>(): SameGeneric<U>;
    }
}
```